# Is it possible to search through json result with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-selectors

What I'm trying to achieve, is to output a json list that contains a list of Css classes, and their corresponding url records, i.e.

```
var jsonList = [{
  "CSSClass": "testclass1",
  "VideoUrl": "/Movies/movie.flv"
}, {
  "CSSClass": "testclass2",
  "VideoUrl": "/Movies/movie2.flx"
}]; //]]>
```

foreach item in the list I am adding a click event to the class...

```
$.each(script, function() {
  $("." + this.CSSClass, "#pageContainer").live('click', function(e) {
    videoPlayer.playMovie(this);
    return false;
  });
});
```

What I'm wondering, is if I can somehow get the corresponding url from the jsonlist, without having to loop through them all again, searching for CSSClass, or adding the url to the link as an attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add an Index and an Item parameter to the callback function in $.each method.

```
$.each(script, function(i, item) { 
   $("." + item.CSSClass, "#pageConainer").live("click", function() {
       videoPlayer.playMovie(item.VideoUrl);
       return false;
   });
});
```

- **"i"** will be a counter of each iteration within the json object
- **"item"** will represent the object in use

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, you just need to capture the your object so that the click function's closure has access to the right thing when it fires. Something like this should work:

```
$.each(script, function() {
    var vid = this;
    $("." + vid.CSSClass, "#pageContainer").live('click', function(e) {
        videoPlayer.playMovie(vid.VideoUrl);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Was just about to answer the same. +1